# Some content overlapping navbar when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I am using Bootstrap to generate a fixed nav bar at the top of the page. Everything is working fine except for one issue. Certain parts of my page are overlapping the nav bar when scrolling. The entire page body is wrapped in a div.

Below are images of the issue.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eua5.jpg

HTML:

```
 <html>
        <head>
          <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

            <title>Saasapp</title>
            <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
            <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
            <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

            <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
            });
            </script>
        </head>
          <body>

        <div class="navbar" id="navbar">

              <%= link_to "/", class: "navbar-logo" do %>
              <%= image_tag 'MGE_logo.png', alt: 'a'%>
              <% end %>
          <a class="" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
          <a class=""><%= link_to "How it Works", "#" %></a>
          <a class=""><%= link_to "Course Directory", "#" %></a>
          <a class=""><%= link_to "Find Event", "#" %></a>
          <a class=""><%= link_to "Course Owners, Claim your Course!", "#" %></a>
        </div>

          <div class= "container">
            <% flash.each do |type, msg| %>
              <%= content_tag :div, msg, class: "alert alert-#{type}" %>
            <% end %>
          </div>
        </nav> 


    <div class="content">
             <div class="maintop">
               <div class="maintopheader">     

               </div>
               <div class="maintopbody">
                  <table style="width:100%">
                    <tr>
                      <td><p>Get quotes from dozen of courses<br>Fast and easy with no obligation<br></p>
                      <%= link_to "Get Free Quotes Now »",new_quote_path, class: 'homebutton' %></a></td>
                       <td>
                      <p>Browse thousands of courses and find<br>the best course for your event<br></p>

                      <%= link_to "Search Courses Now »",new_quote_path, class: 'homebutton' %></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
              </div>

          <div class="content container"></div>
              <div class="mainbottom">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-3 mycol content">
                    <%= image_tag("browseicon.png", class: 'content') %>
                    <p>Browse Courses to Find<br>the Perfect Venue</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3 mycol">
                    <%= image_tag("formicon.png", class: '') %>
                    <p>Fill Out a Form<br>in 5 Minutes</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3 mycol">
                    <%= image_tag("bidicon.png", class: '') %>
                    <p>Course Bid to Host<br>Your Event</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3 mycol">
                    <%= image_tag("findicon.png", class: '') %>
                    <p>Get the Perfect Venue<br>at the Lowest Cost</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <a class="homebutton greenbutton" href="#" role="button">Learn More »</a></td>
                <br>
                <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
              </div>
             </div>
          </div>
```

CSS:

```
body,h1,h2,h3 {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}


a.navbar-logo img {
    height: 48px;
    width: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

#navbar .navbar-logo {
    padding-top: 0px;
   margin-bottom: 0px;
}
#navbar.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.nav-link-custom {
    margin-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: -20px;
}
.navbar-right-custom { 
    color: #F47D00;
    padding-bottom: -20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    float: right;
    font-size: 18px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-weight: bold;

}

.nav-bar-right-custom {
    color: #F47D00;
    float: right;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.navbar-container-bottom {
    height: 90px;
    margin-top: -8px;

}

.navbar-container-top {
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: -5px;
}

.footer-containter {
    padding-top: 30px;

}

.maintop {
    margin-top: 0px;
    height: 400px;
    background-image:url('/assets/home_background_image.jpg');
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black; /* fallback color */
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    color: rgb(255,255,255); /*white*/
}

.maintopheader {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #000000;
    padding-top: 50px;

}    

.maintopbody {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    padding-top: 60px;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.jumbocol {
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    font-size: 26px;
    text-align: center;
}

.homebutton {
    background-color: #F47D00; /* Orange */
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    text-shadow: 0px 0px #000000;
    &:hover {
        box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: rgb(255,255,255); /* White */
        color: #F47D00;
    }
}


.greenbutton {
    background-color: #469F3B; /* Green */
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    margin:auto;
    display:block;
    &:hover {
        background-color: rgb(105,105,105); /* White */
        color: rgb(255,255,255);
        text-decoration: none;
    }
}

.nobold label {
    font-weight: normal;
}
.formbutton {
    // background-color: #469F3B; /* Green */
    // color: rgb(255,255,255);
    opacity: 0.0;

}
.mycol {
    color: rgb(105,105,105); /*dark grey*/
    font-weight: Bold;
    font-size: 40;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

/* Tooltip */
.Customtooltip + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {
    background-color: rgba(70,159,59,0.2); /* Green */
    color: rgba(0,0,0,1.0);
    border: 1px solid green;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

/* Tooltip on top */
.Customtooltip + .tooltip.top > .tooltip-arrow {
    border-top: 5px solid green;
}

/* Tooltip on bottom */
.Customtooltip + .tooltip.bottom > .tooltip-arrow {
    border-bottom: 5px solid green;
}

/* Tooltip on left */
.Customtooltip + .tooltip.left > .tooltip-arrow {
    border-left: 5px solid green;
}

/* Tooltip on right */
.Customtooltip + .tooltip.right > .tooltip-arrow {
    border-right: 5px solid green;
}
#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #A9A9A9;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #303030;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  height: 50px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

#navbar a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.stickycontent {
  padding-top: 100px;
}

body 

{ padding-top: 10px;  background-color: ghostwhite;}
```

Comment: I believe it is a css `z-index` problem. can you show a demo page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing is your code is broken many errors.

May be you can overcome by adding more `z-index` to your `nav` .

Like this

```
#navbar {
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked!

Can you expand on my code being broken? This is my first project and this is still in development but if I am doing anything glaringly against best practice, I would appreciate any pointers! Thanks again

Comment: @JonGolembiewski Can you provide your site `url` if it live , if not i will take your above and codo i will try my best. If this work then add upvote and mark.

Comment: The site is not live but I can try to resend code as I may have made an error when I pasted it.